# How to force pdfminorversion globally?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have a problem with opening PDF files in Acrobat Reader. It comes up with error 131.

I have solved this issue thanks to [How to overcome Acrobat Reader error 131 with a pdfLaTeX doc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/how-to-overcome-acrobat-reader-error-131-with-a-pdflatex-doc) The solution to include `\pdfminorversion=4` works for me, but it's inconvenient to remember about it in every document.

So I have two questions, not being a tex superuser:

- how to force this setting globally?
- how to overcome this error in another way?

I believe it's somehow related to different images formats I use, but I am not sure yet.

On the other hand, should I really care about v1.5? I don't use neither forms nor multimedia, I don't need any file certification.

Comment: As I already commented on your other question: I can not recommend your workaround. Fix your problems with Adobe Reader or your graphics instead.

Comment: Well, while I'm a tex newbie and this happens for me only when I use a certain beamer style, It's kinda hard to produce the simplest example. But I'll try and post my research someday ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### TeX Live

`pdftexconfig.tex` contains these settings. You can locate it via `kpsewhich`:

```
kpsewhich pdftexconfig.tex
```

Then you can put a copy in the local or home `texmf` tree. After putting it in the local `texmf` tree, you need to recreate the file name database:

```
texhash
```

In the file you can change the settings:

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
```

Finally the formats need to be recreated:

```
fmtutil --all
```

or those that are using `pdftexconfig.tex`:

```
fmtutil --byengine pdftex
fmtutil --byengine luatex
```

### MiKTeX (updated with Ulrike Fischer's comment)

MiKTeX uses `pdftexconfig.tex` for the format generation. It can be found via

```
`kpsewhich pdftexconfig.tex`.
```

Example:

```
...\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\config\pdftexconfig.tex
```

This file is a generated file, example:

```
%%% DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! It will be overwritten.
%%% Run 'initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex' to edit configuration settings
%%% for pdfTeX.
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfdecimaldigits=3
\pdfhorigin=1 true in
\pdfoutput=1
\pdfpageheight=297 true mm
\pdfpagewidth=210 true mm
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfpkresolution=600
\pdfvorigin=1 true in
```

Thus `initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex` opens an editor (`notepad`) for the file `pdftex.cfg`, the default contains:

```
%% pdfTeX configuration file. Run 'mthelp pdftexcfg' for parameter help.
```

The command `mthelp pdftexcfg` opens the [manual page for `pdftex.cfg`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pdftexcfg.html).
For example, add the line

```
pdf_minorversion 4
```

The creation of a format file (see below) will trigger the writing of `pdftexconfig.tex` from `pdftex.cfg` and it will contain the following line

```
\pdfminorversion=4
```

appended at the end after the default settings.

All formats (memory dump files) can be regenerated by

```
initexmf --dump
```

Or the dump files that are using `pdftexconfig.tex` can be selected manually:

```
initexmf --dump=pdftex
initexmf --dump=pdflatex
initexmf --dump=luatex
initexmf --dump=lualatex
```

Perhaps you need to try admin mode: Add `--admin` to the command line calls.

This more "official" procedure has one drawback, `\pdfobjcompresslevel` seems not to be supported by `pdftex.cfg`.

---

For the latter case the older precedure based on the comments of Speravir might work<sup>1</sup>:

A local texmf tree (root tree) is needed: [**Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/16967)

Then the file `pdftexconfig` from the MiKTeX distribution tree is copied to the new
local tree (the starting points of the paths `...` need to be adjusted, `texmf.new` is the local texmf tree):

```
copy ...\miktex-2.9\tex\generic\config\pdftexconfig.tex  ...\texmf.new\tex\generic\config\pdftexconfig.tex
```

The file name database needs to be updated:

```
initexmf --update-fndb
```

If the file is not found in the right location:

```
kpsewhich pdftexconfig.tex
```

then admin mode might be needed (see below).

The file can be edited to change the value of `\pdfobjcompresslevel`, for example (see description for TeX Live above).

At last the format files need to be regenerated (see above).

<sup>1</sup>It did not work for my single user installation of MiKTeX, because the user configuration directory is used before the local texmf tree and the modified `pdftexconfig.tex` is not used.

Comment: @Speravir Thanks. `pdflatex` and `lualatex` also needed for MiKTeX, the option `--dump` expects the format name.

Comment: Aah. BTW 1: `initexmf --dump --engine=pdftex` won’t work in the wanted manner – it will create  _all_ format files (the same of course for `--engine=luatex`). BTW 2: I wrote about differences about administrative and user mode in MiKTeX, but Ulrike wasn’t fully happy with it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex

Comment: Deleted all my comments, which are used for answer.

Comment: @Speravir Without an option (`--dump=<key>`) `--dump` recreates _all_ formats.

Comment: Yes, it was only to show, that the `--engine` option does not work here.

Comment: Everything looks great. I have tested it for a while with little problems, but I'll try again and accept this answer, thanks!

Comment: In miktex `pdftexconfig.tex` is created automatically from `pdftex.cfg` everytime a format is build. So the correct way to change the option is: run `initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex`. This will open a local `pdftex.cfg`. Add `pdf_minorversion 4`. Save the file. Update the FNDB. Then rebuild the formats.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I have edited the solution accordingly. Also I have made a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/feature-requests/311/) for the missing setting of `\pdfobjcompresslevel`.

Comment: For newer versions of TeXLive, the command to recreate the formats seems to be `fmtutil-sys --all` ; using `fmtutil --all` doesn't change the pdf version that pdftex outputs.