# Placing an image in Beamer Poster headline and an Inkscape pdf_tex in the body results in broken PDF

Tags: beamerposter, inkscape

I am trying to place a PNG-Image in the headline of a beamer poster, while using a pdf_tex from Inkscape in the body. It works perfectly fine in TexStudio and the preview shows me a nice result. But Acrobat says

> There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.

However, both chrome and firefox open the file without any problems. I boiled it down to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait, size=a0, scale=1.7]{beamerposter}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
    \includegraphics[height=10cm]{test.png}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{figure}
    \def\svgwidth{0.5\textwidth}
    \input{test.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The test.png is an image I created with paint, it has a resolution of 1746 x 546 pixels. The pdf_tex file is a simple circle, no filling color, no text, no nothing.

Comment: Which parameters did you pass to Inkscape to create your LaTeX file of it? Using `inkscape -D -z --file=$file --export-pdf="${file/svg/pdf}" --export-latex=` with a local SVG file and your MWE produces a valid A0-sized PDF on my device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the same on my machine, executing Inkscape not via the GUI, but the cli. Effect is the same, error persists. Note that the error comes up on Acrobat, not Acrobat Reader and does not appear in e.g. the Chrome or Firefox browser. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214064/beamer-pdf-generated-with-pdflatex-on-linux-wont-open-with-windows-adobe-reader?noredirect=1&lq=1). The problem is to embed both a vector graphic (in my case the .pdf_tex) and a .png file into the same document. Adding

```
\pdfminorversion=4
```

at the beginning of the document solved the issue.