# latex background image issue

Tags: backgrounds

Using the Latex eso-pic package I am inserting a background image using the following lines:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
 \AtStockLowerLeft{
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{picture}}}

\begin{document}
...
```

This works; every page now has my picture as the background. However, as soon as I insert a picture in any of my chapters and I open the created *.pdf document using adobe reader (after succesfull compilation using pdflatex), adobe crashes with the following message: "There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (131).". I use the following lines for inserting pictures:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{centering}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{my_picture}
 \par\end{centering}
 \protect\caption{This is my picture.
 \label{fig:my_picture}}
\end{figure}
```

I have the feeling that this is caused by the fact that I'm trying to draw two pictures on top of each other (background + in-text picture). But I have no idea on how to solve this. Any ideas?

Below I added an example:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

%Uncomment following lines to enable background picture (note that there is a 
%bug right now, for some reason having a background image and iserting images
%using \includegraphics does not work correctly. It does compile but *.pdf
%document can not be opened.)
%\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
% \AtStockLowerLeft{
%  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background}}}

\begin{document}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\chapter{Introduction \label{chap:Introduction}}

\section{Background}
Blabla

\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{figure_1}
 \caption{This is my first picture.}\label{fig:figure_1}
\end{figure}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\chapter{Conclusion \label{chap:Conclusion}}

\section{Conclusion}

We can draw the following conclusions:
\begin{itemize}
 \item Conclusion 1
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{figure_2}
 \caption{This is my second picture.}\label{fig:figure_2}
\end{figure}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\end{document}
```

This code compiles fine and I can open the resulting PDF file. However, as soon as add the background by uncommenting the comment lines compiling is no problem but viewing using acrobat reader is a different story: "There was a problem opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code!

Comment: @ebo Thanks for the pointer, I just added a MWE.

Comment: provide your image. I suppose that the problem is located in the pdf of the image.

Comment: I found that when using the same image for both figure_1 and figure_2 (can be any image, tried at least 4 of them), there is no problem. The problem occurs as soon as I use two different images for picture_1 and picture_2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution in this post:
[How to overcome Acrobat Reader error 131 with a pdfLaTeX doc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/how-to-overcome-acrobat-reader-error-131-with-a-pdflatex-doc)

Adding the following line at the very beginning of the tex file did the trick

```
\pdfminorversion=4
```

Answer (score 1):

use it this way:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{my_picture}
 \caption{This is my picture.}\label{fig:my_picture}
\end{figure}
```

`\centering` is a switch and not an environment and `\caption` itself starts a new paragraph. And for `width=1.0\columnwidth` the `\centering` is not needed, the image is already of linewidth

Comment: Inserting a figure works perfectly the way you described. However, the problem open the pdf file is still there; "There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (131)."

Comment: try a different viewer for a test.

Comment: just tried to open it using evince pdf viewer (on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and Chrome browser buildin viewer (on my Windows 7 machine). Guess what, it opens without any problems in both cases. So I only have the problem with Adobe reader (on my Windows 7 machine). I'm using Adobe Reader XI 11.0.0.