# pdflatex generates PDF which Acrobat Reader wouldn't read

Tags: graphics, pdftex, acrobat

I have the following minimal example (`cracks.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{spirale}
\includegraphics{raman}
\end{document}
```

The graphics files are:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxn3heje30w3tgb/spirale.png?dl=0
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/17uif9fguxmwe0j/raman.pdf?dl=0

The PDF generated by `pdflatex cracks.tex` cannot be viewed in Acrobat Reader XI (Windows 7). The error message is “the document is damaged and cannot be repaired”.  Evince can display the document, and if I switch the graphics or change their sizes, it works mostly even in the Reader.

Somehow the PNG seems to trigger the trouble because I can replace `raman.pdf` with another image and the problem persists.

Why is this and what can one do about it?

Comment: At least, I could open an view the PDF in Acrobat on MacOS :-(

Comment: Confirmed. AR-9.4.1 (Linux) produces a similar error message.

Comment: I suggest you resave your .png by copy-pasting it into a new file and try again.

Comment: `raman.pdf` seems to be problematic. Replacing it with `example-image.pdf` from pkg `mwe` doesn't produce the error.

Comment: acroread 9.5.5, does not like it either. But AR does not have a problem with `ramman.pdf` it self

Comment: @AlexG try outcommenting the PNG, then then AR has no problem with the file from pdflatex.

Comment: Already did it. :-)

Comment: @AlexG dis you also try the blank line between the two images?

Comment: Yes. On a page of its own, `raman.pdf` is ok.

Comment: @AlexG perhaps you should add that to your answer

Comment: Curiously, replacing `spirale.png` with `ctan-lion.png` also makes the error disappear. Maybe both files are flawed and cannot coexist?

Comment: @AlexG doesn't that just prove that the PNG is the problem?

Comment: If you replace `raman.pdf` with `example-image.pdf` (and keep the PNG) the error also goes away. What now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51609/discussion-between-daleif-and-alexg).

Comment: Got ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick? Try `mogrify -strip <image file name>` to remove metadata. Might help if the image has some off-syntax cruft there. In general, Adobe products are more finicky about opening PDF with errors. This is an advantage. Many times I have created an erroneous PDF that could open just fine in the built-in TeX document reader, and in Linux Evince, but not in Adobe Reader for Linux or any Adobe products on Windows. The problem was the PDF, not the software. I could identify the problem by uncompressing the PDF and looking in a hex editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is reproducible in an older version (9.4.1, Linux) of AR which refuses to display the document.

`pdflatex` of TeXLive-2016 with up-to-date packages was used to process the document.

On the other hand, a PDF produced with `xelatex` or `lualatex` is OK.

Further tests replacing files one by one identified **`raman.pdf`** to be the problematic file, that `pdflatex` cannot embed correctly.

As a work-around for `pdflatex`, without the need to repair it, the problematic file could be encapsulated into a PDF-XObject:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{spirale}
\xsbox{Raman}{\includegraphics{raman}}\theRaman
\end{document}
```

Comment: The suggested edit of `raman.pdf` didn't help. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test this, probably due to broken LaTeX packages in Ubuntu 16.04. `Argh, internal LaTeX3 error!`

Comment: I marked as “answered” because I now use xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this issue, you just have to had the following line at the top of the `.tex` before the `\documentclass{}` line:

```
 \pdfminorversion=4
```

as suggested in this conversation : [How to overcome Acrobat Reader error 131 with a pdfLaTeX doc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/how-to-overcome-acrobat-reader-error-131-with-a-pdflatex-doc)